# How to download suitable proprietary drivers for WiFi and Bluetooth

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, ubuntu-drivers

I run Ubuntu 20.04. Bluetooth and WiFi often misbehave, I have tried looking up fixes but I can't find anyone who have the same problems like I do - my Bluetooth works fine until it doesn't (after some normal usage) and I need to constantly reboot to get it back running.

I have tried to implement some fixes meant for general bluetooth problems but no avail. Note that I am a complete beginner and so I am not able to debug the issue myself.

I am tired of this and I want to install a proprietary driver for Bluetooth hoping that that would solve the issues. I already run one proprietary driver for Nvidia GPU and things seem to be okay with that I guess.

However, I can't seem to find any options for any proprietary drivers for anything other than the graphics card in "Additional Drivers"
[look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NWXT.png)

How can I "locate and download" the suitable proprietary drivers for my hardware so I can activate it in this "Additional Drivers" menu.

I might be saying stuff that are completely wrong or stupid but please provide some guidance if you have any to offer in my case. I don't need one more article with random terminal code. I need to understand what's going on.

output for lshw -C network

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 31
       serial: 3c:91:80:46:89:3b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.8.0-53-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:150 memory:a4200000-a43fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 10
       serial: 98:fa:9b:0c:10:c8
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-53-generic firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4504000-a4504fff memory:a4500000-a4503fff
```

output for lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #14 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM470 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5005 (rev 01)
07:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

output for dmidecode -s bios-version

```
BGCN17WW
```

Comment: You don't describe the wireless problems that you're having. What hardware are you running on? What kind of wireless card? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `lspci` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Bluetooth turns off suddenly and won't turn back on until (toggle switch in settings won't work) until I reboot my system.
I'll post commands output in following comments.
As for the kitten (now a big boy cat) it is a Persian male cate :)

Comment: @heynnema I've edited the question - it now contains the details you asked for. Thanks for trying to help out.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, you didn't tell me what wireless problems you're having, and I need the EXACT make/model of your computer so I can check your BIOS for you.

Comment: @heynnema Hey, it's been a while. I've doing some research to better understand the issue since my problem is still not fixed.. After a restart, everything is working fine and in place. After a while, the bluetooth adapters/drivers (donno what's the difference) suddenly disappear and I can't seem to find any bluetooth related software anywhere on my system.. I can only find the bluetooth hardware when I use the "lshw" command but not with any other "adapter?" related command like "lspci" - "hcitool" - "lsusb" and what not..

Comment: @heynnema continuing on from my previous message - I am just emphasizing on the fact that it seems to work until it doesn't and the drivers disappear until I restart my computer. The visual implication of this is that the GNOME bluetooth switch doesn't turn on or has no effect (aka broken switch).

Finally, I was able to find out that I have a Qualcomm Atheros bluetooth adapter.

I think the problem is with the adapters/drivers for my hardware but I need someone to tell me what's the issue EVEN IF it has no fix because it is driving me crazy.

Thanks!

Comment: Try booting to a Ubuntu Live 21.04 USB/DVD and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @heynnema okay I will.. but what if it doesn't.. what could be a potential cause of this sudden "unloading of drivers" ? I hope you can give me some helpful keywords to work with.. Thanks!

Comment: By booting to a Live 21.04 USB, we'll try eliminating something wrong with your 20.04 installation, vs a hardware problem.

Comment: Also, you gave me your BIOS info, but you haven't told me your EXACT make/model of your computer (third request).

Comment: @heynnema Ach yes, sorry, here it is : IdeaPad L340-15IRH Gaming

Comment: @heynnema I will try the live boot as you advised.. I am trying to iron out the problem on 20.04.. I am learning some stuff in the process. but if (when) all my attempts fail I will definitely do the live boot but I am quite invested in figuring this out (on 20.04), like some form of puzzle.

Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: You may have missed my point. Booting to a Ubuntu Live 21.04 USB will tell us if you have a software problem on 20.04, or if you have a hardware problem that no software will fix.

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

Lenovo IdeaPad L340-15IRH Gaming

You have a very old BIOS, version BGCN17WW. There's a newer BIOS available, version BGCN33WW, dated 14 Dec 2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds539787-bios-update-for-windows-10-64-bit-l340-15irh-gaming-l340-17irh-gaming).

[image]

**Note**: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model #.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: Can't thank you enough - though the BIOS update package you provided is labelled as for Windows 10.. Does it make a difference that I am on Ubuntu.. If the model number is correct should I just go ahead and update BIOS?

Comment: @TheFeadow Yes, you should update the BIOS. Some BIOS can be directly updated from the current BIOS... you'll have to check it. If you don't have Windows to install it, you can try FreeDOS http://www.freedos.org/

Comment: @TheFeadow Status please...

Comment: Hello kind man, I am sorry I just recently finished my exams (3rd year engineering finals so yeah..) and didn't want to mess with my computer before I finish. Thanks for your patience with me!! I will attempt your fix today and report back to you.

Comment: @TheFeadow Hope the finals went well. Let me know if the BIOS update helps.

Comment: FIrst of all sorry for the delay. The fix didn't help. Bluetooth still stops working suddenly and the only fix seems to be a reboot. I reinstalled ubuntu again and again.. I updated my BIOS.. I tried every solution I can find - many of which were solutions for people who described the same issue and benefited from the solution. Thanks for your patience and assistance but at this point I have wasted a great amount of time debugging this issue and nothing seems to work. I have drawn a personal conclusion that Ubuntu is not as robust as it claims to be..

Comment: .. at least when it comes to Wifi and Bluetooth

Comment: @TheFeadow Back on June 17 I asked that you try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if the problems persist. Did you ever do that?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I can't really test the WiFi problem since it randomly exists/doesn't exist on restart and restarting a live USB boot is like resetting the machine. However, the Bluetooth problem does persist, yes.

Comment: @TheFeadow Did we discuss re-seating the modem/bluetooth card in its socket?

Comment: No, I use a laptop though, does that still apply?
Also, the Bluetooth and WiFi issues seem to happen independently - the occurrence of one does not necessitate the other - so I don't think it's hardware (forgive me if I am remarkably wrong I am still an amateur)

Comment: @TheFeadow You say that the Bluetooth problem happens when booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, yes? That eliminates a software problem on your normal installation, and possibly points to hardware. The  wireless problem would require more testing, yes?

Comment: I used Windows 10 on the same Laptop a year and a half with no Bluetooth issues. Problems started as soon as I switched to Ubuntu. Also, the fact that restarting my Laptop causes Bluetooth to work again (temporarily before the Bluetooth driver disappears again from "hcitool -dev" listing), makes me believe that it is some sort of software issue/incompatibility that causes drivers to unload.

As for the live boot, I guess if the "Ubuntu system files/drivers/controllers" are incompatible with hardware, it wouldn't matter whether Ubuntu is installed or live booted? I don't know.

Comment: I don't know how to further test the WiFi, my poking around has led me to understand that the driver will randomly not load on startup and it will take a couple restarts/reboots to get it to load again... after which there are no issues as long as the computer doesn't shut down/restart.

Comment: @TheFeadow I guess that I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: You've been kind, helpful and very patient.. Thank you very much.. Wish you all the best.